# Inserted USB-Stick prevents Ubuntu from Booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I run Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS on a Lenovo L13 Yoga.
When my USB drive is inserted before boot, it gets stuck after the end of the boot sequence. When I remove the USB drive at that point, it shows the following error messages (that I copied from the bootlog) and proceeds to boot normally.

The USB drive works fine outside of that.

I tried a different USB drive and my system can boot with that one inserted.

I tried formatting the USB stick to FAT32 and NTFS, but nothing changed.

I know the boot sequence is finished because I used Grub Customizer and the 'echo' command to display a message after every boot command to see where the problem happens.

I have trouble finding related problems because all I get is people having trouble booting from USB, which is not what I am trying to do.

Please tell me if I can provide any additional information, that might help to figure out why this is happening

```
 device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: Dev sda: unable to read RDB block 0
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
```

Update: Boot sequence from grub.cfg

```
        recordfail
    savedefault
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5147e4a0-81c2-440a-ba09-ae762f4304fb
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.2.0-39-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic root=UUID=5147e4a0-81c2-440a-ba09-ae762f4304fb ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
```

Update2:
BIOS Boot Order:

1. Ubuntu
2. Windows boot manager
3. Internal SSD
4. Linux firmware updater
5. Lenovo cloud

everything else is excluded

[image: BIOS Boot Order]

Update3: A direct comparision of the relevant part of the bootlog between booting with and without the USB drive inserted.
bootlog with USB:

```
EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): mounted filesystem 5147e4a0-81c2-440a-ba09->
-Gen-2 kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB FLASH  DISK  7.76 P>
-Gen-2 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
-Gen-2 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 62259200 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.>
-Gen-2 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
-Gen-2 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
-Gen-2 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, do>
-Gen-2 kernel: usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
-Gen-2 kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 >
-Gen-2 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
lines 901-923/3158 26%
```

bootlog without USB

```
EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): mounted filesystem 5147e4a0-81c2-440a-ba09->
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.11 running in system mode (+PAM +AUD>
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Hostname set to <sabaca-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga-Gen-2>.
-Gen-2 kernel: Lockdown: systemd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man ker>
-Gen-2 systemd-crontab-generator[245]: ignoring /etc/cron.d/anacron because it >
-Gen-2 systemd-crontab-generator[245]: ignoring /etc/cron.d/e2scrub_all because>
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/modprobe.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/postfix.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File Syst>
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Reached target Slice Units.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Reached target Mounting snaps.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Reached target Local Verity Protected Volumes.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
-Gen-2 systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
```

Comment: Is this just that your bios is trying to boot from usb as the first priority? I appreciate you can boot with a different USB in, but as a workaround can you just change the boot order to boot preferentially from your installed Ubuntu system?

Comment: My boot order is
1. ubuntu
2. windows boot manager
- then everything else.
The problem happens after I choose to boot my installed Ubuntu in the GNU GRUB 2. I should've checked this earlier, but the problem also happens when choosing the Windows Boot Manager, so it's not a Ubuntu exclusive Problem.

Comment: I've completely disabled boot from USB in the BIOS now, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please tell us details about the two USB drives: 1. brand name and model for each of them; 2. Size of each of the USB drives; 3. Age of the USB drives (guess if you don't know) - It seems to me that there is a buffer or read error with the problematic USB drive, maybe when booting, that the [primitive?] driver used by grub cannot see it correctly, but later on, when Ubuntu is running, another driver is used, and that driver can manage the USB drive.

Comment: I'll call the one that blocks booting A and the other one B. 
1. I don't know unfortunately 
2. A is 32GB and USB 3.0, B is 8GB and USB 2.0 
3. A is new, I bought it a few months back, B is old, at least 8 years.

I have a 480GB SanDisk SSD Model#: SDSSDE30 that I tried also and it doesn't block the boot. These are all the storage devices I have on hand to test right now.

Comment: I sometimes have issues when plugging in flash drives. My system changes internal drive from hd0 to hd1 and flash drive is then hd0. So then system does not boot. I go into grub and change hd0 to hd1 and it works. But that is only where I have custom simplified boot stanzas that rely on the hd0 type entries. Normally grub just works.

Comment: I've now attached the boot-sequence. Any suggestion what I could try to change? I don't understand why it tries to read anything from the USB-drive.

Comment: @Sabaca, It is possible that 'A' is quickly recognized and therefore seen as the first drive, and you BIOS system is set to boot into the first drive. (Drive B and the SSD are slower to be recognized and let the internal drive be recognized as the first one.) Please boot into the BIOS system and browse its menus. I don't know what they look like, but there should be a menu where you can decide the boot order and maybe also decide if you want to make it possible to boot into USB drives ...

Comment: @sudodus boot from USB is disabled in my BIOS. I've added my BIOS boot order to the Main Post for reference.

Comment: @Sabaca, I'm sorry, but I don't understand what is happening and I don't know what else you can do except to avoid booting with the problematic USB pendrive connected.

Comment: @sudodus thank you and the others for trying, I will update the post if I ever figure it out, it's not a very pressing problem to have to re-plug the pendrive after all.